# Atasco con bucles

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones

¡Hola! Estoy empezando con JavaScript y estoy atascada con un ejercicio. No consigo dar con como debo hacer la segunda parte del ejercicio, mezclando bucles y condicionales :(

Este es el ejercicio:

```
 // Crea una variable soloA que empiece valiendo 0.

var soloA= 0
// Crea una variable soloL que empiece valiendo 0.
var soloL= 0

// Utilizando la propiedad .length de los strings, podemos obtener un número con la longitud total de una cadena de texto.
// Si usamos mensaje.length obtendremos el número 51, que es el número de letras y espacios dentro del mensaje.
var mensaje = 'Una langosta azul es un animal difícil de encontrar';


// Ahora crea un bucle for que empiece en 0 y llegue hasta el final de la longitud de la cadena de texto contenida en la variable mensaje.
for (i=0; i<mensaje.length; i++)
{console.log (i)}
// Vamos a combinar bucles y condicionales añadiendo dentro del bucle las condiciones:
// => Si la letra para esa posición es igual a la letra 'a', sumamos +1 a la variable soloA
for (a=0; a<soloA; a++)
{if (soloA === "A")}
soloA += 1;

// => Si la letra para esa posición es igual a la letra 'l', sumamos +1 a la variable soloL
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Cuál es el problema que obtienes?... ¿Qué haz intentado?...

Comment: Hola Carmen, bienvenida, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: ¡Hola! Si, claro, lo intenté de varias formas y nada. No he puesto lo que he intentado porque me da vergüenza, probablemente es una catetada jajajajajaja:

Comment: No te hagas problema, pero tiene que subir algo, es norma del sitio.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código en ella

Comment: Si! Eso hice :)

Comment: ¿Tienes la descripción del ejercicio? Generalmente no basta solo con ver el código, si uno no sabe lo que se quiere lograr, ningún código parece incorrecto.

Comment: En replit, que es desde donde debo hacerlo, me aparece incorrecto las dos últimas cosas que me piden, diciéndome que: "La variable soloA vale 7 después del bucle" y "La variable soloL vale 4 después del bucle". No se si te refieres a eso.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca la consigna del ejercicio (qué es lo que te piden hacer). También vendría bien que coloques un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por cierto, tienes un error de sintaxis aquí: `{if (soloA === "A")} soloA += 1`, me imagino que ese cierre de llaves encerraría también a `soloA += 1;`

Comment: Te doy una pista, en el bucle que tienes que añadir condicionales, tienes que usar el mismo bucle que en "mensaje" y no con soloA, así: for (i=0; i<mensaje.length; i++) y dentro del cuerpo del bucle, mirar si la letra actual de mensaje, es igual a A y si lo es, entonces incrementar soloA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos tu código:

```
for( i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i++ ) {
   console.log(i)
}
```

Este sección si bien está bien construida, imprimirá en consola los números desde el "0" hasta el "51", no es lo que se pide.

```
for (a=0; a<soloA; a++)
{if (soloA === "A")}
soloA += 1;
```

Esta sección cuando la "estilizas", queda así:

```
for( a = 0; a < soloA; a++ ) {
    if( soloA === "A" )
}
soloA += 1;
```

Como puedes ver, **soloA += 1;** queda fuera del for.
Acá hago un alto, la elección del estilo de codificación, es personal, los códigos funcionan igual, ahora, lo que has hecho, "ayuda" a cometer errores, te sugiero que adoptes un estilo "más claro"..

Una muestra de como podría quedar:

```js
let soloA = 0;
let soloL = 0;
let mensaje = 'Una langosta azul es un animal difícil de encontrar';

for( let i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i ++ ) {
    if( mensaje[ i ] === "a" ) {
        soloA ++; 
    }
    else if( mensaje[ i ] === "l" ) {
        soloL ++; 
    }
}

console.log( "En el texto hay " + soloA + " letras 'A' y " + soloL +  " letras 'L'" );
```

Answer (score 3):

*Desplegando* tu código, tu tienes lo siguiente:

```js
var soloA = 0;
var soloL = 0;

var mensaje = 'Una langosta azul es un animal difícil de encontrar';

for (i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

for (a = 0; a < soloA; a++) {
  if (soloA === 'A')
}

soloA += 1;
```

En donde `soloA += 1;` queda fuera del `for`, por lo que nunca va a incrementar.

Además ese último `for` no tiene sentido alguno, bastaría con que utilices el primer `for` ya que ahí se aplica el bucle en base a la cantidad de caracteres de tu variable `mensaje`.

Entonces en ese `for`, mientras va iterando cada caracter, tendrías que verificar si dicho caracter es la letra `a` o la letra `l` para que dependiendo a esto, incremente tus variables `soloA` y `soloL`:

```js
for (i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i++) {
  // console.log(i);
  if (mensaje[i].toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    soloA += 1;
  }
  if (mensaje[i].toLowerCase() === 'l') {
    soloL += 1;
  }
}
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var soloA = 0;
var soloL = 0;

var mensaje = 'Una langosta azul es un animal difícil de encontrar';

for (i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i++) {
  // console.log(i);
  if (mensaje[i].toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    soloA += 1;
  }
  if (mensaje[i].toLowerCase() === 'l') {
    soloL += 1;
  }
}

console.log('Cantidad de letras A:', soloA);
console.log('Cantidad de letras L:', soloL);
```

Comment: comentario eliminado!!

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos.

Efectivamente ahora he entendido que estaba poniendo otra variable creada de forma innecesaria, además de como me decís, no incluir el "soloA" en los corchetes.

Me ha costado ver durante un buen rato todo y probar para entenderlo, la verdad es que este apartado se me ha atascado mucho y me está costando avanzar.

También me ha costado entender lo que pedía el ejercicio en si, no me expliqué bien y, aun así, lo habéis entendido jejejejej.

Ojalá y pronto tenga yo esa soltura y conocimiento!!

MIL GRACIAS